# Can your company down grade your title

Tags: salary

After asking for a equity review hoping to get my salary closer to market value, my boss is trying to down grade my title instead(removing senior from my title).  Can they do this?

Comment: Please specify the country and add a country tag ?

Comment: Your boss is a jerk for taking that approach.  You may have to test the waters to see what your real market value is.

Comment: If you are in the US the answer is Yes.

Comment: We simply can't answer this question (with respect to the one who has tried). You've listed no country so we can't address the legal aspect (assuming you're even asking about the legal aspect). Without the country, we can only address it as an individual company, which is off-topic. Either way, I'm voting to close.

Comment: I'm guessing you used your current Title as the way to compare your salary to that Title's market value, right?

Comment: No country tag = VTC unclear.

Comment: Ah, the ole "can I have a raise/promotion" vs "you are lucky we let you keep your job at all" response. They don't really want you as an employee, or they do want you but think they can manipulate and exploit you to get you to accept less but still produce for them just the same. Not really any good way out other than leaving, for most people in most situations, or take the abuse and hope the next boss is better (good luck).

Comment: Not a lawyer, but in some places, a demotion in rank without reason could be considered [constructive dismissal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_dismissal).

Comment: USA: You find yourself a new job, and when you've got it and signed the contract, you tell your boss that you feel bad about taking his valuable money away and leave.

Comment: Europe: They can change your job title, but not reduce your salary. You find yourself a new job, meanwhile you adapt your work output and quality based on your reduced job title. When you have a job and signed the contract you give your notice.

Comment: I think you may have got what you asked for.  It's just not what you wanted!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they can.  Companies can put whatever title on your position that they wish.  They can call you anything from "First Lord of the Admiralty" to "Kermit the Frog" as a job title, and it's entirely their call.

Whether or not you'd choose to work for such a company is something I'd carefully consider.

For this situation, look at your job responsibilities.  Find the title on the salary surveys that most closely matches your role in the company, and stick with that no matter what they call you.

Your boss is hopelessly out of touch if he believes that changing your title is the solution to this issue.

Comment: If they are paying above market rates, they can call me "Junior Apprentice Shitbird" and I will like it.

Answer (score 3):

You asked for a review, they did the review and concluded that:

- you don't deserve the amount of money a senior should get based on
  the current market
- or they do not believe you are truly qualified at the senior level
- or they do not think your tasks are actually senior tasks
- or they simply don't have the budget to pay that amount.

So they downgraded your position. That's the risk in asking for a review. It doesn't always go the way you want it to go.

It's clear you won't be getting more money at this place, so if that is important to you then you need to look elsewhere.